# How to shorten the Qt make process?

Tags: qt, build-process, nmake

I have downloaded an open source Qt that target on Windows. Since I am using the VS2010 command prompt to do the installation, it automatically set the platform to msvc-2010. When I am trying to build using nmake, it took about 7-8 hours to complete the installation. During the process, I have notice that Qt is compiling the libraries which I don't need like *javascript*.

May I know how can I shorten the build process since I am focusing on desktop development?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As @tibur said, you can use `jom`, which is a kind of "parallel nmake". You can also pass several options to Qt's configure, some of which are:

1. `-release` or `-debug`: build only release or debug binaries
2. `-nomake demos`, `-nomake examples`, `-nomake tools`: don't build well, demos, examples or tools.
3. `-no-webkit`, `-no-qt3support`, `-no-script`, `-no-scripttools`: disable certain Qt modules.

There may be more, `configure.exe --help` will tell you all the options available to you.

Comment: May I know the tools is for what purpose? Is it some sort of debugging tool?

Comment: I think the tools are things like `assistant`, `designer`, `linguist`, `qdoc3`, etc... Everything in the `<source>/tools` folder. If you only need the libraries and nothing more, you can disable this.

Answer (score 4):

The one big library taking the longest is webkit. If you don't need webkit, you can pass

```
-no-webkit
```

and the build time should go down significantly. Most other flags (like -nomake demos, -nomake examples, see rubenvb's answer) are microoptimization in comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [jom](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/03/27/speeding-up-visual-c-qt-builds/).

> jom is a clone of nmake to support the execution of multiple independent commands in parallel. 
>   It adds the -j command line switch similar to GNU make.

Answer (score 2):

I configure Qt to build vcproj files and then use **`vcbuild`** which supports multi-threaded builds, using /M4 or /M8 option:

> /M`<number>`      Specifies the number
>   of concurrent builds to run, if
>   possible

You can also build with **`devenv.com`** which builds concurrently if you've configured that in your IDE options.

Both of these are  like `jom`, apparently, but this works w/o installing anything else.